# How to remove an npm package

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

I have a package.json file, and a package-lock.json. I am trying to uninstall a module which is no longer required however whenever I use npm install again it comes back. How do I remove an old unused package?

I have tried clearing the cache, and deleting the package-lock.json file, removing the package from the json file and deleting the file manually, uninstalling via npm. No matter what I do, it comes back.

Comment: If you are removing it from package.json then it shouldn't come back but maybe it's dependency of some other module in package.json.

Comment: It's not even listed in package.json, only in the package-lock.json file. I've tried manually deleting from there, uninstalling, but it keeps coming back. I've tried other modules as well, and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

First, run

```
npm uninstall $MODULE
```

where `$MODULE` is the name of the module you want to uninstall. Then, open your project's `package.json` file, and make sure that the entry for this module is gone in the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` section. Make sure to check both, and if it's still in there, remove the appropriate line manually.

Now (or later), when you run `npm install` again, the module will not be installed anymore.

If you want to clean up your project, you might in addition delete the `package-lock.json` file and the `node_modules` directory, and run `npm install` to get a clean install from scratch. However, this is not required to make sure that the module does not get installed any more.

Comment: I have tried this. I only have three things listed as dependencies in package.json, so it's not coming from there. I tried uninstall and deleting manually but it keeps coming back, which ever one I try.

Comment: delete package-lock.json and npm install again? Are u kidding here without introducing potential caveats of doing that?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to uninstall a package say "express".

You have to uninstall using

```
npm uninstall --save express
```

Comment: That didn't work, it's still in the package-lock.json file and the folder remains under node_modules.

Comment: can you please provide your package.json and package-lock.json as well as the dependency you are trying to uninstall

Comment: I think the issue was using the azure cloud tools. I have now set up Visual Studio Code and am not having the same issues.